# Velocity along curve given velocity in one axis

Tags: calculus, physics

Let's say that I have some particle travelling along a 2D trajectory mapped out by some infinitely differentiable function $f$ (in this case $f(x) = x^{-1}$). I know the velocity of the particle solely in the $x$ dimension (i.e. $\frac{dx}{dt}$), but I want to find the particle's velocity along the trajectory. How might I go about doing this?

(Although I need to know this for a physics problem, I felt that the question actually fell more generally into the realm of mathematics. If others disagree and think this should be moved to the physics stack exchange site, feel free to comment below.)

Comment: don't understand what you said "the velocity of the particle solely in the x dimension"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the particle's velocity is a vector, and you should represent is as such. You know the graph of the particle's actual motion, which is a large piece of information you should take advantage of. Don't think of it as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ - think of it as $y = \frac{1}{x}.$ Notice that the velocity vector is generally represented as $<\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt}>.$ You noted that you were given $\frac{dx}{dt},$ and by parametrics, you know that $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}.$ I think you can take it from here. Hope this helped!

Comment: I do understand that the particle's velocity is a vector. I phrased the question the way I did because this was a problem in Lagrangian mechanics, and I chose to use the x coordinate, and *only* the x coordinate, of the particle as my generalized coordinate system. For that reason, I don't care about the velocity vector, only its magnitude so that I can determine the kinetic energy of the system. I should have been able to figure this out, but for some reason the answer was eluding me. Nonetheless, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry I misinterpreted your problem. We can find the speed by taking the magnitude of the velocity vector by using $s = \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^{2} + (\frac{dy}{dt})^{2}}.$